# jQuery: datepicker causes entire page to flicker!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

when i set a custom yearRange for my datepicker (ie. +- 100 years), during the focusin event on the datepicker input field, a page flicker occurs. also, when changing the month/year inside the datepicker gui, the datepicker flickers.

i think it is because more than +-20 years in the datepicker yearRange is maybe too much DOM for the datepicker to generate, but i am not 100% of this. i do know that below +-20 years in the dateRange, this flicker does not occur.

here is my datepicker code:

```
            // add datepicker
   var today = new Date();
   $('companyVarDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: (today.getFullYear() - 100) + ':' + (today.getFullYear() + 100)
   });
```

is there any way to fix this flicker? thanks!

Comment: There's not much generated either way, calculations are done when each page shows in the picker.  Which browser are you seeing a flicker in?

Comment: firefox 3.6.3 and jQuery UI Datepicker 1.8

Comment: @Nick Craver @Garrett - I'm seeing the flicker too, in Firefox 3.6 and jQuery UI 1.8. See the jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KKReb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to not do the `today.getFullYear()`. That [current year is assumed](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-yearRange) when you set the + and - year values. Instead, you want to do something like this:

```
var today = new Date();
$('#companyVarDate').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '-100:+100'
});
```

The flicker goes away in Firefox 3.6. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/KKReb/1/

Answer (score 0):

Were you using 1.8.7?

There was an issue with the datePicker full page flicker in Firefox that was fixed in JQuery UI 1.8.7

See http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5493

Changeset https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/7832fd8e9c59c6cdc2465bb039c12c87fca85b5d